# Values in unordered_map are changing itself

Tags: c++, hash, unordered-map

Having trouble with unordered_map named visited.
The goal of visited is to mark visited vertices in graph which are pairs of char and int.
The problem is that values in visited change itself even if I changed them manually after the initialization of visited.

I tried simpler method to declare hash for pair of int and char but it didn't work.
Then I tried to change pair of char and int to int, by multiplicating char by 1M and adding int.
However it didn't work either.

Details:
When function BFS is called again then the same key (i.e. key is pair<'c', 1> converted to int)
is called in condition:

`if ( visited[(pair.first - '0')*1000000 + pair.second] == 0 )`

then the condition is passed even if I assign to this key a value of 1 earlier.

```
#include <vector>
#include <unordered_map>
#include <list>
#include <utility>

using namespace std;

typedef std::pair<char, int> p;

// define hash for pair<char, int>
struct pair_hash
{
    template <class T1, class T2>
    std::size_t operator() (const std::pair<T1, T2> &p) const
    {
        return std::hash<T1>()(p.first) ^ std::hash<T2>()(p.second);
    }
};



void BFS(pair<char, int> v, 
        unordered_map<int, int> visited, 
        unordered_map<pair<char, int>, vector<pair<char, int>>, pair_hash> graph)   {

    // Maybe int instead of a pair<char, int> as a key will work...
    int x = (v.first - '0')*1000000 + v.second;
    if (visited[x] == 0) {

        // Create a queue for BFS
        list<pair<char, int>> queue;
    
        // Mark the current node as visited and enqueue it
        visited[x] = 1;
        queue.push_back(v);
    
        while(!queue.empty()) {
            // Dequeue a vertex from queue
            v = queue.front();
            queue.pop_front();

            // Get all adjacent vertices of the dequeued
            // vertex s. If a adjacent has not been visited,
            // then mark it visited and enqueue it
            for (p P : graph[v]) {
                int y = (P.first - '0')*1000000 + P.second;

                // Problem lays here
                if (visited[y] == 0) {

                    // now I set converted pair<'c', 1> to int to 1:
                    visited[y] = 1;
                    // After 1, 2 calls of function named BFS the condtion
                    // if ( visited[ converted pair<'c', 1> to int ] == 0 )
                    // is passed even if I set it to 1 earlier


                    queue.push_back(P);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
int main() {
        unordered_map<pair<char, int>, vector<pair<char, int>>, pair_hash> graph;


        // Container for marking vertices as visited
        unordered_map<int, int> visited;
        for (auto kv: graph) {
            int x = (kv.first.first - '0')*1000000 + kv.first.second;
            visited[x] = 0;
        }


        // Graph traversal
        for (auto kv: graph) {
            BFS(kv.first, visited, graph);
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: That hash method is (probably) really weak. `std::hash<char>` and `std::hash<int>` will (probably) be identity functions so what you (probably) are doing is `p.first ^ p.second`.

Comment: Why do you use a map and not a set?

Comment: Unrelated: Do you have a 64-bit machine? You could try using a simple re-write of the hash function to get a better hash value:
`struct pair_hash { static_assert(sizeof(size_t)==8); std::size_t operator() (const std::pair<int8_t, int32_t> &p) const { return static_cast<uint64_t>(p.first) << (4*8) | static_cast<uint64_t>(p.second); } };`

Comment: @TedLyngmo A hash collision would make the map inefficient, but it would not lead to the problem OP is describing. (Just noting, your input is still valuable)

Comment: @ypnos Right, I should have marked it _unrelated_.

Comment: @ypnos good idea, thanks for pointing out, this resolved an issue

Comment: @ypnos what is an identity function? So simply saying my hash is very prone to collisions, isn't it?

Comment: @jms Guess your question was directed at @TedLyngmo. He suggests that `std::hash<char>(x) = x` (identity). I don't know the std hash functions, but reckon the rationale here is, if you only have up to 255 buckets, why even bother with some intermediate computation? Now if the same applies to `std::hash<int>`, and I have no idea if it does, you could conclude your simple xor is inefficient at preventing collisions in your scenario. In general however, mind the No Free Lunch theorem: Every hash function is as good as anything, if not tailored specifically to your input distribution.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identity_function I just think you could create another identity-like function that has _no_ collisions at all.

Comment: ... and yes, you'll have heaps of collisions with your current hash function.